# Change bitbucket pull request username

Tags: git, bitbucket, config, pull-request

I want to change my local git username (bitbucket).
I have already change the username for commit using :

**$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"...**

it works fine for the commit, but for the pull request the previous username appear again.

Comment: How are you raising a pull request? Using the web UI right? Or is there another way?

Comment: You'll probably need to amend those commits. Changing the config only applies to future commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+author

Answer (score 1):

For last commit, amend commit:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

For commits earlier, rebase with hash:

```
git rebase -i COMMIT_HASH
# and follow the interactive rebase
```